# SQL transpose and join

Tags: sql, pivot, transpose

table A looks like this:

[image: ![enter image description here]

I need to join this table A to table B but require the results which are duplicated in A due to multiple same ID's to be transposed and pivoted. Please could you help. Seems simple but cant crack this evening:

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: Recommend you add a tag for the rdbms you are using (mySql, SqlServer, Postgres, or whichever it is).

Comment: Please update your question to show the SQL you’ve managed to write yourself. I assume that the second image is the result you want to achieve, rather than Table B? If so, please add Table B to your question and show both tables and the result as tables, not images - so that someone who wants to try a solution can copy your data

Answer (score 0):

The solution here was to perform a subquery on the data from table 1 and provide a row number to then use in the main query in a sum case when rowid = 1 will provide the first examiner etc and so on in separate cols

```
(SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a.examiner ORDER BY a.examinerid DESC) as ROWID,
```